# Why can I add a post in here, even though I've been suspended?

Tags: support, meta, account-suspension

I find this odd that I can post something in this area even though I've been suspended from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), so why is that, or is that normal?

I take it that these two areas are two different animals; so are they?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because Meta Stack Exchange is not part of Stack Overflow. Look at the site URL... compare it to the Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow URLs. They are separate.

Meta Stack Exchange is the Meta of all metas for the Stack Exchange network. Single site suspensions only affect that single site and its meta. It doesn't affect your account anywhere else on the network.

Keep in mind that, while Stack Overflow is a huge percentage of the traffic of the entire Stack Exchange ecosystem, it's still its own entity with its own moderation team and rules. What's unacceptable on one site *may* not be unacceptable on others. It often is, but not always. As such, if a suspension on one of the 170 network sites blocked your access to all of them, that would make little sense. I know of users who are very active and valuable users on one community but fail to be respectful on others but we let each site decide individually if a user is welcome or not.

There are staff members, particularly the Community Managers, who have moderation abilities on all sites but they often do little of the moderation on those sites in many cases, leaving the decisions to the moderators. This site, however, is moderated **only** by staff. So, too, only staff are able to issue network-wide suspensions.

So, you're not suspended here on purpose. If you do whatever caused your Stack Overflow suspension here you may *also* earn a suspension here but that likely won't affect your access to the rest of the network sites because network-wide suspensions are relatively rare.

Comment: You figure that it's owned and operated by the same people. If it were me and I owned a chain of bars and music clubs, I'd want to bar someone from all of those, because I am the owner. Is this not the same case here? We all need to step through the same door, as it were.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yeah, but are these the same people that own both of those establishments or are different owners, that's the analogy I'm trying to establish here. Edit: Now this person went and deleted the comment I was answering to, why is that?

Comment: @Bathsheba well there you have it; I think I have a pretty good case then about the basis of my questiona and my analogy ;-) you shouldn't delete your comment btw. They are relevant as are mine.

Comment: @Fred-ii- better analogy is if you own bars, malls, schools, etc. If one misbehaved while drunk late night at your bar, you shouldn't assume he'll misbehave while sober during day and should not ban him from your malls or schools. Those are different entities.

Comment: Keep in mind that you're  suspended by the elected moderators on SO, not by SE staff.

Comment: @ShadowWizard *Haha!* - well, you probably don't know the same owners that I know ;-) some do own bars and night clubs and music clubs where they won't let the same guy in. But what you say does make sense I think, yet this all boils down to "the police/the state" who would have control over all of those.

Comment: @rene Ok, so isn't Stack Overflow part of the Stack Exchange where we all need to login from? I mean, if someone is barred, then why let them through the front door to begin with? edit: and able to post?

Comment: @Fred-ii- indeed. And when one is doing something REALLY bad, or just repeating same bad things in several sites, SE staff can issue network wide suspension. It happens, though not often. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ok, that makes sense, thanks.

Comment: @Fred-ii- well, technically yes. In fact they run an OpenID server which you can use to login to sites SE never heard of. Do you want to be banned from all those servers as well when you crossed a line on SO?

Comment: @rene For the former, thanks. For the latter *"Do you want to be banned from that as well when you crossed a line on SO?"* - kind of an odd question. If what you're asking is if I'm looking for trouble, the answer would be no. Why would you ask me that?

Comment: @Fred-ii- No is the correct answer, you passed the test.

Comment: @rene I've always thought of myself as being a good pupil.

Comment: @rene Btw, the Winter Bash should probably have a "Dunce cap" for a hat *lol!!* - If you don't know what that is, ask me and I'll tell you. I thought of posting on meta about it as a feature request, but I think that'll just get shot down. I for one think it would be rather funny though, but they may not go for it since that would probably open a can of worms for those who have been suspended and to not let anyone know of it, as in not "airing someone's dirty laundry" *as it were*.

Answer (score 6):

If you do something *really* naughty then you can get a simultaneous suspension from all sites.

But suspensions tend to be issued on a per-site basis due to their issuance by moderators who tend to have moderation privileges on only particular sites.

Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow Meta are moderated by the same folk: suspensions issued in Stack Overflow also apply to its meta site.

Comment: I guess  I am not aware of how everything rolls here then. Is there a link you can reference?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: There are dark corners indeed. Just don't repeat whatever you did to get the suspension; on any site.

Comment: I edited my comment above, please reload it, being the latter part of it.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: The moderator suspension note would be a good starting point.

Comment: Well first you tell me *"Just don't repeat whatever you did to get the suspension; on any site."* and now you're basically wanting to know what it was with *"The moderator suspension note would be a good starting point"*. So, if you really want to know, you'll need to be clear on what you're asking. Or did I misinterpret?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I don't understand that invective: I'm not asking you to reveal the reason for your suspension. That's between you and the mods. Apply a common sense rule: just behave yourself on these sites. Simples.

Comment: The note about it and in a nutshell was about a comment I posted under one "my" (old) questions, 2 actually, being the same.  As for behaving, I do... it's someone else who yanked my chain to begin with. Being suspended for such pettyness is just that, petty. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Stack Exchange is network of sites, each site has its own topic, its own set of users, etc. Stack Overflow is one of them, though the biggest. This one (Meta Stack Exchange) is another, separate, site in the network. You also have sites for gaming, cooking, and many many more. List is [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions). And suspension is done per-site, and does not affect other sites.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Take ownership of your own actions.  Don’t blame the actions of another user (because they themselves had the proper action taken against them) for your actions.

Comment: @Ramhound mind telling me what that's about and what it has to do with the question? I'm not up for discussion on that matter.